# MDX - Format of Month member in dynamic string

Tags: mdx

I have a dynamic string to calculate the current month from my time dimension using MDX. The string looks like this:

```
StrToMember("[Time Sales Stage].[Time Sales Stage YQMD].[Year].&[" 
            + format(now(),"yyyy") + "].&[Q" 
            + format(datepart("q", now())) + "].&[" 
            + format(now(), "MMM" + "]"))
```

The **"MMM"** part in the end, should return ***"May"*** but it now actually returns ***"Mai"*** which is my local language name for the month. When this value is returned, my query fails due to that the member name being asked for, is not a valid member.

Is there any way to format the **"MMM"** part to return the **english name** of the month?

Comment: Seeing that this code is used to query a SSAS Tabular model, I changed the language of the model to be 1033. Still no luck in getting the correct answer when asking for the abbreviation of month - using "MMM".

Comment: Ended up making a new Time Hierarchy using Month Number, not month name abbreviation. Then my code looks like this:

    StrToMember("[Time Sales Stage].[Time Sales Stage YQMD].[Year].&[" 
            + format(now(),"yyyy") + "].&[Q" 
            + format(datepart("q", now())) + "].&[" 
            + format(now(), "MM" + "]"))